# Некорректно работает lastInserId

Tags: php

Нужно генерировать ссылку на текущую игру, я ничего лучше не придумал как использовать **lastInsertId**, пишу на ООП, и выходит так что результат выполнения кода, в итоге выводит 0, вместо последнего id

```
class CheckStart extends Db {
    public $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = $_POST;
    }

    public function checkStart() {
        if ( isset($this->data['do_start']) ) {
            $hp_default = 1000;
            // Стандартное количество хп
            $sql = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `game` (`hp`) VALUES (:hp)");
            $sql->bindParam(":hp", $hp_default, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sql->execute();
            echo "success";
            // header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }

    public function generateLink() {
        // Генерирования ссылки на игру
        $sql = $this->connect()->query("SELECT `id` FROM `game`");
        $sql = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sql = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();
        echo $sql;
    }
}

$start = new CheckStart;
$start->checkStart();
$start->generateLink();`
```

Comment: Не эксперт, но у вас последовательность запросов такая: `INSERT` --> `SELECT` --> `lastInsertId()`. Это не правильно. `lastInsertId()` должен быть после `INSERT`a. Зачем вам этот `SELECT`? попробуйте удалить первые 2 строчки из `lastInsertId()`

Comment: @Manitikyl Я думал такая последовательность правильная, сначала добавление, а потом вывод уже обновленное информации из БД.

Но все же сделал все как вы и сказали, результат не изменился, по прежнему выводит 0

`public function generateLink() {
   // Генерирования ссылки на игру
   $sql = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();
   echo $sql;
  }`

Comment: Когда вы делаете `INSERT`, ответ уже сразу приходит и записывается в `lastInsertId`. А своим `SELECT` вы скорее всего его обнуляете.

Comment: Измените для теста: `echo "success";` на `echo $this->connect()->lastInsertId();`. Если и опять будет `0` то тогда будем думать.

Comment: @Manitikyl Изменил, но опять `0`

Comment: Ну значит не правильно создана таблица `game` там нет ключа с авто-инсертом.

Comment: @Manitikyl По началу я так же подумал, но в таблице есть `A_I`. Странно все это, когда я работал без ООП, то все было как положено, `lastInsertId` работал без ошибок, и возвращался последний `id`

Comment: ваше ооп тут нулевое. `A_I` есть и при добавлении новой записи он автоматически увеличивается?

Comment: @Manitikyl Стараюсь как могу, посмотрел уроки и теперь практикуюсь. Да, `A_I` увеличивается. Но вот что заметил: скорее всего действительно проблема в структуре таблицы, только что пробовал без ООП, и с совсем другой таблицей, оно тоже не работает, но почему так? - для меня это остается загадкой

Comment: у вас тут ООП и не пахнет, покажите mysql вывод "show create table game"

Comment: вангую, `->connect()` создает подключение заново

Comment: @teran Ну в фукнции `connect()` находится подключение к БД, я ее вызываю каждый раз как приходится работать с Базой

Comment: вопрос в том, каждый раз там новое подключение создается, либо если уже подключено, то возвращается старое. мне кажется, всегда новое. insert id доступен на время сессии подключения пользователя. при новом подключении его уже не получить.